# Execute procedure in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following SQL code:

```
EXECUTE userAanmaken 
@domeinNummer=1,
@gebruikerNaam='Jansen',
@gebruikerPass='Jaap',
@gebruikerEmail='jan@piet.nl',
@gebruikerVN='Joop',
@gebruikerTV='van',
@gebruikerAN='Heha',
@gebruikerGS='M',
@gebruikerOL='Hoog',
@gebruikerGD=2011-11-11
```

This code affects the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE userAanmaken
(    
IN domeinNummer INT(11),
IN gebruikerNaam VARCHAR(45),
IN gebruikerPass VARCHAR(45),
IN gebruikerEmail VARCHAR(45),
IN gebruikerVN VARCHAR(50),
IN gebruikerTV VARCHAR(10),
IN gebruikerAN VARCHAR(50),
IN gebruikerGS VARCHAR(1),
IN gebruikerOL VARCHAR(30),
IN gebruikerGD DATE
)

BEGIN 

DECLARE lastID INT;

INSERT INTO Gebruiker(Domein_idDomeint) 
VALUES (domeinNummer);

SET lastId=LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Inlog (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,UserName,UserPass)
VALUES (lastId,gebruikerNaam,gebruikerPass);

INSERT INTO GGevens (Gebruiker_idGebruiker,Email,Voornaam,Tussenvoeg,Achternaam,Geslacht,Opleiding,GebDatum)
VALUES (lastId,gebruikerEmail,gebruikerVN,gebruikerTV,gebruikerAN,gebruikerGS,gebruikerOL,gebruikerGD);
END$$
```

When i run the execute statement it returns with a syntax error.

How do i define the parameters in the SQL execute statement?

Comment: Can you copy > paste what syntax error you get?

Comment: MySQL uses `CALL`, rather than `EXECUTE` - I don't know that `EXECUTE` is supported as an alias to `CALL`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html  `EXECUTE` is used for executing prepared statements, which is different from a stored procedure.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas The error: http://i.imgur.com/ZvsUxWJ.png

Comment: Try to use `CAL`L instead of `EXECUTE` and tell If that works for you.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas http://i.imgur.com/DmvIFf8.png same :/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you missing date quotation marks `''` on `DATE`:

`@gebruikerGD='2011-11-11'`

Maybe you need to use `DELIMITER //` in beggining of procedure and `DELIMITER;` in end of procedure. Check [documentation](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx).

Comment: If you use *MySQL* try to use `CALL` instead of `EXECUTE`

Comment: Updated answer, check It.

Comment: Fixed it with by using:

CALL userTestA (@domeinNummer=3,@gebruikerNaam='Jansen',
@gebruikerPass='Jaap',
@gebruikerEmail='jan@piet.nl',
@gebruikerVN='Joop',
@gebruikerTV='van',
@gebruikerAN='Heha',
@gebruikerGS='M',
@gebruikerOL='Hoog',
@gebruikerGD='2011-11-11')